# express does not include assets

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to load assets to my EJS file using express and it does not work. I just get message

> Cannot GET /assets/main.css

Even I made loader in my main app:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets')));`
and after printing the path I see that its correct and the files exsists. So after using

`<link href="assets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">` I can't reach the file. Where the problem could be?

Comment: Pretty sure that `app.use()` statement makes `./assets` the root folder.  Check and see if you can open `/main.css` rather than `/assets/main.css`.

Comment: My bad, sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Right now, your `app.use(...)` statement is saying: I want the directory `./assets` to be served whenever I navigate to my app, in other words, when I open my browser to `http://localhost`, serve whatever is in the folder `./assets`.

You are then trying to access the file `main.css` at `http://localhost/assets/main.css`.  It isn't there, it's at `http://localhost/main.css`.

You have 2 options:

1. Change your `<link>` tag to point to where the asset actually is:

```html
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2. Change your `app.use()` to host the `./assets` folder at a different endpoint:

```js
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets')));
```